# sorting python list based on "dependencies" from dictionary

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose I have the following list `foo` that I would like to sort:

```
foo = [63,64,65]
```

To inform the sort, I have the following dictionary of "dependencies", where if a **value** is in a list for a **key**, that **value** must sort higher than the **key** in list `foo`:

```
bar = {
    63: [64, 65],
    64: [65]
}
```

For example, looking at list `foo`, we see the value `63` at index `0`.  But, checking the dictionary `bar`, we see that `63` has "dependencies" `64` and `65`, so both those values must sort higher in `foo`.

I'm confident I could cobble something together, but am interested in algorithms and/or other approaches to solve this sorting scenario.  Thanks.

**UPDATE:**  Many in the comments have pointed out this is likely a graphing / topological problem.  Thanks for that, as this is, in fact, part of a larger task of sorting nodes in a graph.

**Update:** [toposort](https://bitbucket.org/ericvsmith/toposort) was sugggested to look at, and this precisely fits the bill.

Comment: Just for completeness, would you mind including in your post what you have already tried? I would also add your desired output to your post.

Comment: This really sounds like a graphing problem

Comment: That's a fair request @rahlf23.  This sorting is part of a more complex action, and to be honest, have not yet tried to sort this list.  But will update with any attempts or solutions.

Comment: @gregb212, you're absolutely right.  In fact, these "dependencies" are reflecting edges, and the values, nodes.  This sorting scenario is a subset of a larger task to determine order of "downstream" nodes in a graph.  That's very helpful, had not considered there might be a more holistic approach to this.

Comment: This sounds like a topological sort - have you looked into that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks all, the suggestions to look to graphing / topological sorting feels like the right way to go.

Comment: Also see https://pypi.org/project/toposort/, a ready-made project that handles topological sorting for you.

Comment: Note that technically, `64` is not a value for the key `63`. A list *containing* `64` is the value for the key `63`.

Comment: Yes @Acccumulation, that is true.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, this looks great!  This is precisely the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, putting all the comments together:

Your situation corresponds to a directed graph, where each edge is a dependency. The right way to sort a directed (acyclical) graph, or short DAG, is called [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).

In Python there is already a package that can do this, [`toposort`](https://pypi.org/project/toposort/).
It requires, however, that your values are sets, not lists, but that is easy to fix:

```
from toposort import toposort_flatten

bar = {
    63: [64, 65],
    64: [65]
}

graph = dict(zip(bar.keys(), map(set, bar.values())))
sorted_graph = toposort_flatten(graph, sort=True)
```

Since it sound like your graph may contain entries which are not in `foo`, you could sort `foo` like this:

```
foo = [63,64,65]
foo_set = set(foo)
foo_sorted = [x for x in sorted_graph if x in foo_set]
print(foo_sorted)
# [65, 64, 63]
```

Or, if the graph is a lot larger than the list you want to sort (and iterating over it takes a lot of time), build a dictionary:

```
graph_sorted_lookup = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted_graph)}
foo_sorted = sorted(foo, key=graph_sorted_lookup.get)
```

Comment: This approach is perfect, as is the library toposort as per suggested in comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Is that always possible? If the graph is `a -> b, c -> d -> b` and you want to sort the list `[a, b, c]`, you cannot remove `d` from the graph even though it is not present in the list, because otherwise `c` could sort before `a` and `b`.